# Email is blank on Apple Email Client (Mail app)

Tags: node.js, amazon-ses

I am sending notification emails through ses(aws) and I am able to view the message build with html on gmail app but on apple mail client the message is blank.

```
    let message = JSON.parse(singleMessage.body);
            let params = {
                Destination: {
                    ToAddresses: message.toAddresses,
                },
                Message: {
                    Body: {
                        Html: {
                            Charset: "UTF-8",
                            Data: message.body,
                        },
                    },
                    Subject: {
                        Charset: "UTF-8",
                        Data: message.subject,
                    },
                },
                Source: environments.EmailSender,
            };
ses.sendEmail(params).promise()
```